# Python packages for Spark on datanodes

Tags: python, numpy, apache-spark, pyspark

We want to use Python 3.x with packages like NumPy, Pandas,etc. on top of Spark.

We know the Python distribution with these packages needs to be present/distributed on all the datanodes for Spark to use these packages.

Instead of setting up this Python distro on all the datanodes, will putting it on a NAS mount to which all datanodes are connected work?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, putting the packages on a NAS mount to which all the datanodes are connected will work up to dozens and perhaps 100 nodes if you have a good NAS.   However,  this solution will break down at scale as all the nodes try to import the files they need.  The Python import mechanism usese a lot of os.stat calls to the file-system and this can cause bottle-necks when all the nodes are trying to load the same code.